# Sabre: How to pass 2 OTA_AirPriceRQ in EnhancedAirBookRQ?

Tags: sabre

How can I pass 2 OTA_AirPriceRQ in 1 EnhancedAirBookRQ for booking RoundTrip in Sabre?

Consider the below example:

```
<EnhancedAirBookRQ>
    <OTA_AirBookRQ>
    ...
    <FlightSegment>
       <!-- Segment 1 Details -->
    <FlightSegment/>

    <FlightSegment>
       <!-- Segment 2 Details -->
    <FlightSegment/>

    <OTA_AirPriceRQ>
        <PriceRequestInformation>
            <OptionalQualifiers>
                <PricingQualifiers CurrencyCode='INR'>
                    <PassengerType Code='ADT' Force='true' Quantity='1'/> 
                </PricingQualifiers>
            </OptionalQualifiers>
        </PriceRequestInformation>
     </OTA_AirPriceRQ>
     <PostProcessing IgnoreAfter="false">
            <RedisplayReservation/>
     </PostProcessing>
   <EnhancedAirBookRQ>
```

So from above code,I wanted to pass another OTA_AirPriceRQ for Segment 2, to achieve RoundTrip.

But I get error when I repeat OTA_AirPriceRQ Tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with SegmentSelect element under PriceRequestInformation/OptionalQualifiers/PricingQualifiers/ItineraryOptions.

By default, all segments will be priced the same way, so unless you want to do something special for particular segment/s, you don't need to add extra qualifiers.

Answer (score 0):

`OTA_AirPriceRQ` is used to get pricing information (price breakdown) for a specific travel, however travel details (origin, destination, classes, flight numbers, etc) you have to provide in `OTA_AirBookRQ`. It's a part of a `EnhancedAirBookRQ` transaction you are using (but should be defined prior to `OTA_AirPriceRQ` in request xml)

To sum it up - when you provide in `OTA_AirBookRQ` information about outbound and inbound flight, then 1 OTA_AirPriceRQ returns you full pricing information (no seperate AirPriceRQ is required)

You can find more information here
https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/book/orchestrated_air_booking